# Angular Provider access in ui router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I tried changing `service` into a `provider` to get access `config` phase.
The `provider` is in other module.

```
var app = angular.module('ops.services');

app.constant('opsConstants', {
    GID: 'UA1'
});

app.provider('OpsConstantService', OpsConstantService);

OpsConstantService.$inject = ['opsConstants'];

function OpsConstantService(opsConstants) {
    return {
        $get:function() {
            return {
                OPSCONSTANTS : opsInsightConstants,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`My app module` depends on the same, and **DI** has been provided.

```
var opsApp = angular.module('opsApp', ['ui.router',  'ops.services', 'angular-momentjs']);
```

And,now, In my app, `routing` I need to access the constants value.

```
opsApp.config(routerConfig);

routerConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider','OpsConstantServiceProvider'];

function routerConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,OpsConstantServiceProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home/dashboard/");

    $stateProvider
        .state('Modal', {
            url: .....
```

But if I try to log `OpsConstantServiceProvider.OPSCONSTANTS` it's undefined.

Why so ?

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: If you need a constant, ask for a constant. app.provider => app.constant('OpsConstant', {const1: 1, const2: 2})

And then access it from there.

Comment: @Vitalii There are many more `constant` functions as such. This is just a part example.

Comment: Sure. But constant doesn't mean *not an object*.  Group your constants in proper named objects (one, two, five, no meters) and register this objects in angular's DI with app.constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
function OpsConstantService(opsConstants) {
    return {
        OPSCONSTANTS : opsInsightConstants,
        $get:function() {
            return {
                // something
            }
        }
    }
}

app.config(['OpsConstantServiceProvider', function(OpsConstantServiceProvider) {
  console.log(OpsConstantServiceProvider.OPSCONSTANTS);
}]);
```

But, this is not good)
Actually what are you trying to do? Gather constants and create one big object?
Then you can do this:

```
app.constant('test1', {test: 1});
app.constant('test2', {test: 2});
app.constant('test3', {test: 3});
app.constant('commons', {});

app.config(['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'commons', function(test1, test2, test3, commons) {
  commons.test1 = test1;
  commons.test2 = test2;
  commons.test3 = test3;
}]);
```